# Getting "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" even though the file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The command `rails s` doesn't work; I get this error message:

```
/Users/homedir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/homedir/projectname/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I checked that the file `database.yml` exists. I modified it and saved it, but I still get the same error. Do you have any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you just write a puts statement just above line `115` in `/Users/homedir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb` file and check the value of `yaml` variable

Comment: I wrote `puts "Value of YAML is #{YAML}!"` and I got this : `Value of YAML is Psych!` before getting the error.

Comment: No not `YAML`, print the value of `yaml` variable. There is one more variable named `path`. You need to check both of these values. For example see the code from rails master branch https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L119-L125 . You need to check `path` by writing puts after line 119 and `yaml` by writing puts after 120.